# Google v8 engine Z-Way

Tags: javascript, python, v8

Well, I wanted to write files to the file system, send mails and do other things which might be not straightforward in the Google V8 engine which Z-Way uses. Python allows easy independent testing and debugging of a script without having to fiddle with the V8 debugger.

Can someone please explain what this guy is saying? I'm trying understand why I should use Python instead of Javascript

Comment: Which guy is saying what?

Comment: I found it at: https://technology.amis.nl/2016/01/14/simple-security-system-using-raspberry-pi-2b-razberry-fibaro-motion-sensor-fgms-001/#comment-8975

Comment: If you search on Python there, or the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

V8 itself doesn't provide any means of system interaction (files, network, executing commands, ...). That's by design: the job of V8 is to deal with JavaScript execution; system integration is defined by the embedder. This separation of concerns provides flexibility for different use cases, for example:

- V8's developer shell `d8` can load files, which is needed for running tests.
- Chrome, for obvious security reasons, provides no direct system access to websites, but does provide clearly defined APIs like XmlHttpRequest, LocalStorage, etc.
- node.js implements a full set of system and networking APIs, because that's what you want on a server.
- your own embedding application can choose to implement whatever system integration it wants :-)

I don't know what kind of V8 embedding Z-Way provides. Apparently it is one that makes it possible to call Python scripts, but also one where the author of that post believes that interacting with the system in general (files, network, etc.) is easier to do with Python. Maybe it's just his personal preference :-)

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer jmrk. I will try to look more into it.